# Algolia React InstantSearch filter false and undefined results

Tags: reactjs, algolia, react-instantsearch

I am using React and NextJS and Algolia's React InstantSearch, I am having an issue trying to filter results that do not equal an attribute I currently have. I have buttons where I want to display hits where `isNew:true` and and another button to show results that are `isNew:false` as well as hits that do not have this attribute as well, so something like `isNew:undefined`.

I have tried the `Configure` connector with `<Configure filters="type:Posts AND (NOT isNew:True)" />` but it does not seem to work as it will only always show hits where `isNew:false`.

Is there a way to have `isNew:false` always include the `undefined` hits as well? I want it to show both types of hits when the button is clicked and if a user visits the route with `isNew=false` declared.

Comment: Can you close the topic by validate the answer if it's ok ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't.
The Algolia engine doesn’t support filtering on null value or missing attributes.

You have the choice between adding the isNew:false attribute to all objects that doesn't already have this attribute or using a tag.

You can check the documentation :

https://www.algolia.com/doc/guides/managing-results/refine-results/filtering/how-to/filter-by-null-or-missing-attributes/